# Can I add a footnote inside a natbib e.g. citation?

Tags: footnotes, natbib

How can I sneak in a footnote in an e.g. citation using natbib?

For example,

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cite1,
  title={Title},
  author={Smithy, A.},
  journal={Journal Name},
  volume={100},
  pages={100--101},
  year={2000}
}
@article{cite2,
  title={Title},
  author={Jonesy, A.},
  journal={Journal Name},
  volume={100},
  pages={100--101},
  year={2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
blah blah \citep[e.g.][]{cite1, cite2} blah blah
\end{document}
```

Using `\citep[e.g.][]{cite1 \footnote{Say something here}, cite2}` throws an error (it doesn't expect nested braces).

End goal looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this isn't something you're doing routinely. For a one-off, I'd just break it up into two different citation commands, even if it meant adding the parentheses manually:

```
blah blah (\citealp[e.g.][]{cite1},\footnote{Say something here.} \citealp{cite2}) blah blah
```

[image: footnote in citation]

(EDIT: I guess you could put the comma and `\footnote` command in the reverse order to get it more like your picture, but I think the footnote marker looks better after the comma.)